# Using proportions directly instead of cbind() in glm() binomial regression is the same [R]?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution

My response variable is a proportion. Is there a difference or it is valid to use directly proportions instead of cbind(Successes, Failures)?

For example:

> glm(proportion ~ other variables, family=binomial)

where, proportion is porportion of successes

instead of:

> glm (cbind(successes, failures) ~ other variables, family=binomial)

If this is right, is there any case where it is an advantage in using cbind()?

Comment: Note that this isn't really a programming question, & it doesn't have a reproducible example, it would be off topic on [SO].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Questions that are only about how to use R are off topic here; this will be closed.*

Regarding the statistical issues involved in this situation, @JeremyMiles has provided a good answer.

For an R-specific response to this, it may help you to read the documentation for [?glm](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/glm.html):

> For a binomial GLM prior weights are used to give the number of trials when the response is the proportion of successes

So you need:

```
glm(proportion ~ other variables, family=binomial, weights=totals)
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer and sorry if this is off-topic. So, I can use weights or cbind(s,f) when number of observation (n) within trials vary. Clear.

Comment: That's OK, @SergioNolazco, now you know. You can use weights when the n w/i trials varies, you just need a vector of n's where the 1st corresponds to the 1st proportion, etc.

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't get the same answer. (And if you think you do, can you provide a reproducible example).

When you use the proportion, you discard information about the level of certainty of the effect. 1 success from two trials is different to 100 successes / 200 trials.

Comment: @jeremy Thanks for your answer. So using cbind() weights proportions based on the number of observations within a same trial? If this is true, I would expect to always use cbind() when number of observations within trials vary, am I right?